# Uniroot function to find the inverse of a custom CDF

Tags: r

I am trying to find the inverse of a custom CDF function

In doing this I have stumbled across the uniroot function which looks to solve inverse functions. I am running into a few errors however, and would greatly appreciate help on this.

My goal here is writing a function along the lines of R's base functions `qnorm` `qexp` etc. but with `qcustom`.

```
# Error 1: (Error in f(x) : argument "p" is missing, with no default)

inverse <- function(f, lower=0.01, upper=500000) {
  function(y) {
    uniroot(function(x) f(x) - y, lower=lower, upper=upper)[1]
  }
}

qcustom <- inverse(function(x, p, a, b) {
  x^2+a+b+p
  return(result)
})

qcustom(0.5) ##when i add in further parameters, e.g p = 0.5 it says it's an unused parameter##
```

Comment: Looks like a `force` problem. currently the `uniroot` part of the `inverse` function is assigned to `qcustom` instead of evaluating it. See https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html. Could you provide some sample of what you expected the function to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start at the beginning:

```r
custom_cdf <- function(x, p, a, b) {
   p*exp(-a*x) + (1-p)*exp(-b*x)
}
```

This has parameters `c(p, a, b)` and let us try to find a pairing of `c(a,b)` that
makes sense for the `range(x) = c(0, 500e3)` as you pointed out that you want.

```r
plot.new()
curve(custom_cdf(x, p = 0.5, a = 1e-4, b = 1e-5), xlim = c(0, 500e3))
```

[image: Getting decent default values]

A reasonable set of values could be:

```r
a <- 1e-4
b <- 1e-5
```

Let us try for multiple values of `p`:

```r
first <- TRUE
plot.new()
for (p in seq.default(0.1, 1, length.out = 25)) {
  curve(custom_cdf(x, p = p, a = 1e-4, b = 1e-5), xlim = c(0, 500e3), add = !first)
  first <- FALSE
}
rm('p')
```

[image: Multiple ps used]

To just the inverse of the CDF, we could just:

```r
xx <- seq.default(0, 500e3, length.out = 2500)
# xx <- seq.default(0, 500e3, by = 10)
# xx <- seq.default(0, 500e3, by = 1)
yy <- custom_cdf(xx, p = 0.5, a = a, b = b)

plot.new()
plot(yy, xx, main = "inverse of CDF = Quantile Function",type = 'l')
```

I.e. we can just reverse the plotting.
So now, this is a picture of the inverse function.

[image: picture of the inverse cdf === quantile function]

Let's use `uniroot` to get one inverse value.

```r
uniroot(
  function(x) custom_cdf(x, p = 0.5, a = a, b = b) - 0.2,
  interval = c(0, 100e50),
  extendInt = "yes"
) -> found_20pct_point
#' 
#' Let's plot that point:
#' 
points(custom_cdf(found_20pct_point[[1]], p = 0.5, a = a, b = b), found_20pct_point[[1]])
```

[image: the found point is on the plot]

Alright, so now we understand everything and we can do what you tried to do:

```r
custom_quantile <- function(p, a, b) {
  particular_cdf <- function(x) custom_cdf(x, p, a, b)
  function(prob) {
    uniroot(
      function(x) particular_cdf(x) - prob,
      interval = c(0, 100e50),
      extendInt = "yes"
    )$root
  }
}
custom_quantile_specific <- 
  custom_quantile(p = 0.5, a = a, b = b)
custom_quantile_specific(0.2)
```

And this works as it yields something close to the desired value.

But regular quantile functions in R does depend on the parameters of the
distribution, so this is good enough:

```r
custom_quantile <- function(prob, p, a, b) {
  particular_cdf <- function(x) custom_cdf(x, p, a, b)
  uniroot(
    function(x) particular_cdf(x) - prob,
    interval = c(0, 100e50),
    extendInt = "yes"
  )$root
}
custom_quantile(0.2, p = 0.5, a = a, b = b)
```